# Change site_libs path of RMarkdown website

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to build a static HTML using RMarkdown. My `_site.yml` configuration is like this:

```
name: "My RMarkdown Website A"
output_dir: ../../_site/web-a
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
     self_contained: false
     lib_dir: site_libs
```

When I knit my RMarkdown, my `lib_dir` folder will be stored on `../../_site/web-a`. Is there any way that I can store my `lib_dir` folder on `../../_site`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure you can do it programmatically using RMarkdown package itself, but you can copy-paste the whole folder over there. It has worked for me.